# Installing APCu on MAMP Server

Tags: php, macos, caching, mamp, apc

I really searched for an answer to my question but only could find solutions concerning Windows installations. As I am using Mac OS X that doesn't help me.

I'm running MAMP Server 4.0.4 with PHP Version 7.0.10 (switchable to 5.6.25) and MySQL 5.6.28. All is installed on a MacMini with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

In the end the MAMP server shall be hosting Owncloud.

As I found out because of the PHP Version in MAMP there is a need for APCu instead of only APC.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to switch to this memcache. MAMP only offers in it's preferences APC or OPcache.

Can somebody help and tell me how to install or set up APCu?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 3):

I've solved by opening the MAMP preferences (`cmd`+`,`) then going to the PHP tab and selecting `Cache: APC`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works for me with MAMP Free version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here the solution:

At the PHP-Options there is a link to activate more extensions (on the right side of the 'Oauth' checkbox).

Here the screenshot of what I'm meaning:

[image]

Click on it and search for 'apcu'. You will find these two lines:

```
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apcu.so
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apc.so
```

This prefix 'MAMP_apc_MAMP' means, that this Option is activated with the APC-Cache setting. Remove the prefix from the first line to get this

```
extension=apcu.so
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apc.so
```

After restarting your MAMP, APCu will be running. Hope I could help.